# Observe Collection Results in Realm with Combine and SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, realm, combine

I am trying out [this quick start for SwiftUI and Combine](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/ios/swiftui/) in order to try and understand how to connect my Realm database to Combine.

The example observes a `RealmSwift.List` and keeps a table populated with its data. This is is a linked list to a child class. I'm wondering how to observe a `Results` collection so I can keep track of any changes to an entire Realm class.

For example, let's say I have a `Workspace` class:

```
class Workspace: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable{
  @objc dynamic var id = UUID().uuidString
  @objc dynamic var name = ""
  @objc dynamic var archived = false
}
```

In the state object, I can set up a `Results<Workspace>` variable like this:

```
class AppState: ObservableObject {
  @Published var workspaces: Results<Workspace>?
  var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
  
  init(){

    let realmPublisher = PassthroughSubject<Realm, Error>()

    realmPublisher
      .sink(receiveCompletion: { _ in }, receiveValue: { realm in
        //Get the Results
        self.workspaces = realm.objects(Workspace.self)
      })
      .store(in: &cancellables)

    realmPublisher.send(try! Realm())

    return
  }
}
```

But when it comes time to observe the object, I can't because `Results` isn't an object (I assume).

```
struct ContentView: App {
  @ObservedObject var state = AppState()
  var view: some View {
    ItemsView(workspaces: state.workspaces!)  
  }
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      view.environmentObject(state)
    }
  }
}

struct ItemsView: View {
  @ObservedObject var workspaces: Results<Workspace> //<!-- Error

  var body: some View {
    //...
  }
}
```

Xcode gives a syntax error on the `workspaces` property:

> *Property type 'Results' does not match that of the 'wrappedValue' property of its wrapper type 'ObservedObject'*

Is it possible to observe a set of `Results` just like we can have a notification listener on a collection of `Results`?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you could hook up a `sink` to `state.workspaces` (`state.$workspaces.sink()`), but in this case, I think you're overcomplicating the problem.

You already have an @ObservableObject in your `ContentView` (`AppState`) that is managing the results for you. So, change `ItemsView` to just take this as a parameter:

```
var workspaces: Results<Workspace>?
```

It doesn't need to be an `@ObservedObject` -- either way, whether it's getting observed in that view or it's parent view, it's going to get re-rendered. It does have to be optional here, since it's an optional value on your `AppState`, unless you want to keep passing it with the force unwrap (`!`), but that's generally a bad idea, since it'll crash if it ever *is* in fact `nil`.

Also, above, in your `Realm` code, make sure it's matching the tutorial that you were following. For example, you have `Publisher.sink` which should really be `realmPublisher.sink`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I'm new to Combine so my understanding is pretty limited. I'll try your suggestions. I did have the `realmPublisher` in my code and just made a typo in my question. I'll fix that. Thanks again.

Comment: I tried what you suggested. I get initial data when the app loads, but I don't get notified of changes. It seems the `AppState()` object isn't propagating its changes. From what I understand, I'd need to make `workspaces` a `@StateObject` in order to bind itself to the parent `@ObservedObject`, but since `workspaces` is not an object, I can't.

Comment: It is not the case that it has to be a @StateObject -- something else must be going on. What happens when you print the contents of workspaces inside the sink?

Comment: Looks like nothing happens. Nothing is printed on updates (I'm making changes in the Realm database directly to trigger a change).

Comment: Well, that means that it's not the Combine part that isn't working -- it's the Realm part

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, `Results` is a struct, and therefore cannot be covered by `@StateObject` or `@ObservedObject`. Your workaround is suitable for now.

Once https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/pull/7045 is released, you will be able to use one of the new Realm property wrappers to embed your `Results` into the view directly. At the time of this posting, that would be `@FetchRealmResults`, but that is subject to change.

Comment: That sounds like exactly what I want. So you would abstract the Publisher stuff and just let me focus on getting `Results` where I need them. I think that's similar to what Core Data does with Combine. Let me know who I need to buy pizza for to get that PR released. 